# Introducing the New "Review" Page

Tags: support, faq, moderation, announcement

I'd like to officially introduce the new Review page! If you've clicked on the [review](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review) link recently, located in the header to the right of your username and list of badges, you may have noticed some changes.

The Review page consists of posts that are automatically flagged by the system as either low quality, first answers, first questions, and late answers. It also contains a list of posts with close votes, delete votes, and suggested edits. This is very similar to the dashboard that the moderators see.

The idea behind the new review dashboard is to make community moderation tasks more efficient by crowdsourcing posts that meet certain criteria that traditionally make them risky or not a good fit for Project Management Stack Exchange.

### **Low Quality Posts:**

I usually see very short answers get caught by this filter. I generally leave a comment, and most of the time users will edit and improve. It's great to see someone get lots of upvotes because of a comment I left that helped them improve their post!

Using the dashboard, you can mark the answer as "Looks Good", if there are no problems with it, or you could leave a comment with suggestions on how to improve the post. If you see a way to improve the post, you can submit an edit, and if you're sure it's of little value, you can recommend deletion. Of course, if you're not sure, you can skip it.

### **Close Votes:**

This lists all of the questions with at least 1 close vote. From the dashboard, you can comment, vote to close, edit and improve, or skip if you're not sure. You can also disagree with the close vote!

### **Suggested Edits:**

The suggested edits dashboard contains edits submitted on questions and answers by users with less than 1000 reputation. It also lists suggested edits on Tag Wikis by users with less than 4000 reputation. Anyone with at least 1500 reputation can vote to approve a Tag Wiki edit.

---

***At this time, First Answers, Late Answers, and First Questions are all still on the old system. Feel free to review those posts using the old legacy dashboard.***

### **First Answers:**

New users who post answers may need guidance on how to write a good Stack Exchange answer, one that's well-detailed and answers the question. Many first time users may try to follow up by asking another question or simply using answers as comments. You can help with guiding comments, edits, or recommending deletion.

### **First Questions:**

New users may not fully understand the scope of the site. As a community, we're starting to do a great job in trying to help these users improve their posts! :)

### **Late Answers:**

In many cases, some old not constructive questions that haven't yet been closed will get spam answers. Depending on the user and what they've posted, I may simply leave a comment, downvote, or delete altogether. Using the review dashboard, you can also take action on these posts, or recommend an action be taken.

We're pretty excited about how this new tool will help our growing community!  If you have any questions about the new review queue, notice any bugs, or have suggestions for how to improve it, post a new question on Meta Project Management. Thank you for participating in the governance of this site and helping to guide and educate new users! :)

**NOTE:  At the time of this post, there are over 145 First Answers, 70 Late Answers, and 36 Low Quality posts waiting for review!  Feel free to jump right in, as there are plenty to keep people busy who are looking for other ways to contribute to the community!**

**UPDATE:**

@aclear mentioned that there are some posts that are fine, but that don't necessarily need action to be taken, such as in the First Posts queue. I did some research on Meta Stack Overflow and found the [New Review Queue: First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146988/new-review-queue-first-posts) announcement, where one of the community managers, Shog9, describes the goals as it relates to posts that are good posts:

> Yes, there's about a 1 in 5 chance that the post you're looking at will be utter crap, or at very least something you'll want to down-vote. But it is *just as important* to provide some sort of feedback to the new authors whose posts *aren't* terrible - whether that's an up-vote, or a comment, or even a small edit that puts a bit more of a shine on their already-useful contribution.

I think that if we take this message into account, there is almost always something we can do to encourage a new user, or turn their post from a 0 voted one into a +3 voted one. I'm not sure how this will work yet on PMSE, but if you see a way to improve a so-so question or answer from a new user into something worthy of your upvote, give it a try.

Of course, if there really is no action to take, and you don't want to vote, just click "Not Sure" :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I like the way the new post review works. I generally limit myself to giving one or possibly two answers an upvote per question. This doesn't mean that all of the others deserve a downvote. So that means I either need to leave a spurious comment, or select "not sure" which seems rather confining.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess we're forced to select "Not Sure" if we don't plan to take any action. However, keep in mind that these are posts from new users, so an upvote to a good post might be a good way to encourage more helpful participation. I'll post an update in my post to elaborate.